# String manipulation to create email address from first and last name at least 4 times

Tags: c#, string, email-address

This program will is giving me the error message:

> use of unassigned variable yourName and use of unassigned variable yourIsp.

If I take the for loop out it will run. I am trying to ask user for name and isp at least 4 times and create email address from first and last name using string manipulation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string yourName; string yourIsp;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name:");
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)            
    yourName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your ISP:");
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    yourIsp = Console.ReadLine();

    char[] separator = {' '};
    string[] yourWords;
    yourWords = yourName.Split(separator);
    string yourFirstName = yourWords[0];
    string yourLastName = yourWords[1];
    string yourEmailAddress = yourFirstName + yourLastName + "@" + yourIsp;
    yourEmailAddress = yourEmailAddress.ToLower();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, your email address is {1}", yourName, yourEmailAddress);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you think this is supposed to do.  It asks for your full name, and then reads four lines of text, replacing `yourName` each time.  So it will only "remember" the last line entered.  Once you've entered four lines of text, it then does the same thing for ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `yourName` and `yourIsp` default values.

```
string yourName = "";
string yourIsp = "";
```

It doesn't know if your `for` loops are going to run for sure *(even though you can tell that they'll each run 4 times)*.

---

Imagine if instead, your loop looked like this:

```
int number;

for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count(); i++)
    number = Math.Max(number, i.SomeValueInTheList);

Console.WriteLine("Largest value in list: {0}", number);
```

If there were no elements in the list, then the loop would never run, and `number` would not be initialized.

---

Store the values in a list, then display them one-by-one. Your overwriting values, and losing all but the last input value.

```
var names = new List<string>();
var isps = new List<string>();

string yourName; string yourIsp;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name:");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    names.Add(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter your ISP:");
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    isps.Add(Console.ReadLine());

foreach (var sentence in names.Zip(isps, (name, isp) => string.Format("Hello {0}, your email address is {1}", name, string.Concat(name, "@", isp).ToLower())))
    Console.WriteLine(sentence);
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work and asked me for 4 names and isp. But for output it only gave me one email address. I mean, I input for names and isps:   Jon Don, Ray Smith, Sam Dam, Rob Mob / hotmail.com, yahoo.com, gmail.com, live.com. It gave me output as Rob Mob email address is robmob@live.com. How do I get all four names to create email addresses.

Comment: @Ralvarez No problem. If any of the answers on StackOverflow help you, please upvote them and/or mark the most helpful as answer. It helps anyone in the future with the same problem find help quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Change `string yourName; string yourIsp;` to:

```
string yourName = null;
string yourIsp = null;
```

The problem is that the compiler cannot safely say if a value is ever assigned to the variables. Although it’s clear from the code that there will be a value assignment four times, it’s not something the compiler can say. Thus, you have to initialize the variables explicitely.

Comment: It is making sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers describe the error.  My post addresses what I *think* you might have been trying to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name:");
    string yourName =Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your ISP:");
    string yourIsp = Console.ReadLine();

    char[] separator = {' '};
    string[] yourWords;
    yourWords = yourName.Split(separator);
    string yourFirstName = yourWords[0];
    string yourLastName = yourWords[1];
    string yourEmailAddress = yourFirstName + yourLastName + "@" + yourIsp;
    yourEmailAddress = yourEmailAddress.ToLower();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, your email address is {1}", yourName, yourEmailAddress);
}
```

Comment: Thank you paddy, that is exactly what i am trying to do. Thanks a bunch.